# Share network access to closed resources in AWS

Tags: networking, routes, share

Is it possible to share access to closed resources in Azure/Aws(access opened via IP) from my public server which has static ip?

I have current setup [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRzN4.png)

I need to connect to my aws servers via my public server.

Answer (score 0):

Create a VPN connection between your static server and AWS. Check out the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html

Create an ssh tunnel or RDP connection to the webserver, then you will be able to connect the databases from there. Generally, this is the purpose of a bastion host.

Comment: Correct, let say I already have VPN between server and AWS, question is about how to access from my laptop via my public server to AWS located server